# right to left excel page layout in python win32com

Tags: excel, layout, pywin32, win32com, worksheet

I am using win32com for writing an excel sheet, but my data is right to left and I want to set sheet layout right to left ( same as Microsoft Excel's Page layout tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetview.righttoleft?view=openxml-2.8.1

`ActiveSheet.DisplayRightToLeft = True`

edit:

To be more explicit...

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

#xl.Visible = True

new_file = r'Drive:\\path\\file.xlsx'
new_book = xl.Workbooks.Open(new_file)

for sheet in new_book.Sheets: 
    xl.Worksheets(sheet.Name).Activate()
    new_book.Worksheets(sheet.Name).DisplayRightToLeft = True

xl.Application.Quit()
```